# Chrome does not rendering svg image

Tags: google-chrome, svg, fullscreen

I have a problem with rendering svg image, but only in Chrome (FF, IE, Edge are OK). I can see only text from image, but there is not any background color from image etc. I need to have image on full screen, and here is my code. Could someone help me, where is the problem with chrome and how to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("bg.svg");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class ="bg"> </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the content of your svg? the way you provided us your code should work in chrome, so nothing we can do with this limited information.

Comment: It is simple image. Background is green color and there is also one sentence. Maybe, will it be better to convert it to some other format? I would like to have it responsive.

Comment: if you have a simple svg your solution should work. Try fixing all your HTML syntax errors (you have a space between `class` and `=`, maybe removing this fixes your problem.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Without further information all we can say is `your code works`

All I did was changing the url from your svg file to a public placeholder svg image. As you can see there are zero issues with displaying this file.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://placeholder.pics/svg/300");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"> </div>
```